# How to indicate middle name is preferred name in professional email signature

Tags: names, email, nicknames

In almost all situations, I prefer to be addressed by my legal middle name. However, in the email signature (what's automatically included at the bottom of the email) of my university email, I must include my legal first name, leading most people in emails to address me by it rather than my middle name. I was wondering how I could indicate in my (professional) email signature that I prefer to be addressed by my middle name. Would I write: *FirstName "MiddleName" LastName*?

Comment: It's quite common where paper files are still used for personal records (such as those for residents in care homes) for the preferred name to be capitalised on the label so that you get labels like Elsie JANET Smith for someone who uses their second name and JAMES Arthur Black for someone who prefers their first one. As most email addresses are not case-sensitive you could try that. I think it would be less confusing than the inverted commas which make it look like a nickname. Also you could sign all the emails you send out with your preferred name. That would help too.

Comment: If your name is Clarence John Smith, you could easily sign "C. John Smith". This has a number of advantages and is very common.

Comment: There is a difference between your *written signature* and the name you sign or indicate in correspondence other than legal papers. Although you might sign your name *Clarence Smith* (to use the example from the previous comment), you can simply put *John Smith* in your email signatures.

Comment: @BoldBen Capitalisation is more often used to indicate surnames, which may not be at either end in some cultures.

Comment: When I first read your question, Andrei, I understood "email signature" to mean "email address" but now I'm not so sure. Did you actually mean "email address" or is the "email signature" a second level of identification not including the domain name?

Comment: @BoldBen By email signature I was trying to refer to what's automatically included at the bottom of my emails. Ex. Best regards, /NewLine EMAIL SIGNATURE

Comment: @BoldBen - an email signature is a standard way of ending an email for professional use. It usually includes a formal ending, your name, and possibly your title and contact information. In a professional setting, your corporate email software will have this as a default ending to all of your emails.

Comment: @Andrei The email signature must be set by your IT department then and the policy of determining the structure of it must have been set either by them or, more likely, by the university hierarchy. Have you asked to see the rules regarding this structure? There may be a standard option to deal with your issue. I can't imagine that you're the only person on the staff who prefers to use a name other than their first given name.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use my first initial and my full middle and full last name, as in E. Gary Gygax. Another option is to use your full first and full last name with your middle initial. Then, add your preferred name just before your last name in quotation marks. An example is Edwin Eugene “Buzz” Aldrin, Jr.

Comment: By your second suggestion, would suggest something like Marc A "Andrei" Adam?

Comment: @Andrei  Yes, if Adam is your last name.

Comment: As Isabel Archer suggests you could easily sign "C. John Smith". 

As BoldBen said the e-mail signature policy must be set by your IT department or the university hierarchy. In the unlikely event there’s no standard option to deal with your issue, if the policy is worth the paper it’s written on it will contain a procedure for dealing with people sharing the same name…

EG, I once worked with five men called Khan, three of whom shared the first name Atif. Should a formal policy demand they used Khan 1, Khan 2, etc, or accommodate their personal choices?